# Is creating a online pet marketplace haram?

Tags: halal-haram, pets

I know that selling pets (cats, dogs, etc) is haram in Islam. Source: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/69770/ruling-on-selling-cats

I am a web developer and am not sure if I can create my client an online store where he intends to sell pets.

Comment: This fatwa only says that selling cats is regarded as haram by some scholars. There is already a post addressing the scholarly views on selling cats.

Comment: It also says that this is the more correct view of the two views.

Comment: That's an opinion regardless what they say as long as there's a contradictory evidenced scholarly opinion it is not binding and the opposite opinion must be respected. And this fatwa doesn't say selling pets (in general) is haram.